# Как вставить HTML из JS функции в th:text в Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Я хочу показывать рейтинг в виде звездочек, рейтинг ( integer ) получаю из `employee.getUser().getAvgGrade()`, мне нужно его значение передать в функцию `stars()`, она возвращает HTML код. А его уже вставить в `th:text`.

Вот моя таблица:

```
       <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
                <th>Schedule</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
           <tbody>
    <tr th:each="employee:${employees}">

        <td th:text="${employee.getUser().getFullName()}"></td>
        <td th:text="${employee.getUser().getAvgGrade()}"></td>
        <td th:text="${employee.getTimeBegin() + ' - ' + employee.getTimeEnd()}"></td>

    </tr>
    </tbody>
        </table>
```

Вот JS функция, которая возвращает HTML

```
  function star(rate) {
    var starHTML = '';
    var rate = parseInt(rate);
    var increment = 0;
    var max = 5;

    while(increment < rate) {
        starHTML += '<i class="material-icons orange">grade</i>';
        increment++;
    }

    while(max > rate) {
        starHTML += '<i class="material-icons gray">grade</i>';
        max--;
    }
    return starHTML;
};
```

Ну и CSS для звездочек

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
  rel="stylesheet">
```

Резюмируя, я просто не знаю, как вызвать метод и вставить результат выполнения метода в `th:text`, чтобы ячейка таблицы отображала HTML, который возвращает метод.

Comment: Зачем значение вставлять в th:text, если его потом надо менять?

Comment: @RomanC, не очень понял, что надо будет менять.
Рейтинг высчитывается, а звездочки возвращают в таблицу функцией.

Comment: Менять надо значения, которые возвращаются выражением. Сразу нельзя передать их в функцию.